# Handle session in Next.js custom 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, next.js

I have an application that I use Next.js. On this application I have a header and I show some documents and user information inside a `Menu`.

On all pages I use `getServerSideProps` and send the data to `pageProps` and handle it on header.

I have a custom 404 page, and I want to do the same thing here, but Next.js doesn't let me use `getServerSideProps` inside 404 page. I can only use `getStaticProps` but I cannot get session inside `getStaticProps`.

Even if I can get `jwt` token somehow, I will be able to make the request to server and make it work but I couldn't find any solution for this.

Is there anything I can do for this situation? I tried to get `jwt` token by cookies - I use `nookies` - but I couldn't get anything.

My 404 page looks like this;

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { getLayoutDefault } from '@/layouts/LayoutDefault';
import { BrowserHead } from '@/components/BrowserHead/BrowserHead';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

// https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#404-page
// https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/custom-error-no-custom-404

export default function Custom404() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <BrowserHead title="404 - Page Not Found" />

      <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
      <p
        style={{
          display: 'grid',
          gridGap: '.62ch',
          gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, auto)',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <a href="#" onClick={() => router.back()}>
          &larr; Go back
        </a>
        <span>|</span>
        <Link href="/">Go to homepage &rarr;</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

Custom404.getLayout = getLayoutDefault;
```